# Syntax error on Ruby script

Tags: ruby, redmine

I need to get past a syntax error in a Redmine plugin. My Ruby version is 2.2.3.

The script is:

```
module RedmineAnonymousWatchers
  module WatchersHelperPatch
    unloadable

    def self.included(base)
      base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
      base.class_eval do
        alias_method_chain :watchers_checkboxes, :anonymous
        alias_method_chain :watchers_list, :anonymous
        alias_method_chain :watcher_link, :anonymous
      end
    end
    module InstanceMethods
      def watcher_link_with_anonymous(object, user)
        return watcher_link_without_anonymous(object, user) unless user && user.anonymous? && object.respond_to?('watched_by?')
        return '' unless User.current.allowed_to?(:subscribe_anonymously, nil, :global => true)
        include_anonymous_watchers_tags
        watched = cookies[:anonymous_token] && object.watched_by?(AnonymousWatcher.new(:anonymous_token => cookies[:anonymous_token]))
        url = {:controller => 'watchers',
               :action => (watched ? 'anonymous_unwatch' : 'anonymous_watch'),
               :object_type => object.class.to_s.underscore,
               :object_id => object.id}
        link_to((watched ? l(:button_unwatch) : l(:button_watch)), url,
                :class => (watched ? 'icon icon-fav' : 'icon icon-fav-off'),
                :onclick => watched ? "return anonymousUnwatch(this.href);" :
                    "return anonymousWatch(#{l(:text_enter_watcher_email).to_json}, #{(cookies[:watcher_mail] || cookies[:author_mail] || "").to_json}, this.href);")
      end
      def watchers_list_with_anonymous(object)
        str = watchers_list_without_anonymous(object)
        remove_allowed = User.current.allowed_to?("delete_#{object.class.name.underscore}_watchers".to_sym, object.project)
        content = ''.html_safe
        object.watcher_mails.collect do |mail|
          s = ''.html_safe
          s << link_to(mail, "mailto:"<<mail, :class => 'mail')
          if remove_allowed
            url = {:controller => 'watchers',
                   :action => 'destroy',
                   :object_type => object.class.to_s.underscore,
                   :object_id => object.id,
                   :mail => mail}
            s << ' '
            if Redmine::VERSION::MAJOR >= 2
              s << link_to(image_tag('delete.png'), url,
                           :remote => true, :method => 'delete', :class => "delete")
              # Redmine < 2.2
              #s << link_to(image_tag('delete.png'), url,
              #             :remote => true, :method => 'post', :style => "vertical-align: middle", :class => "delete")
            else
              s << link_to_remote(image_tag('delete.png'), {:url => url}, :href => url_for(url),
                           :style => "vertical-align: middle", :class => "delete")
            end
          end
          content << content_tag('li', s)
        end
        content.present? ? str + content_tag('ul', content) : str
      end
      def watchers_checkboxes_with_anonymous(object, users, checked=nil)
        str = watchers_checkboxes_without_anonymous(object, users, checked)
        mails = object && object.watcher_mails || @watcher_mails
        mails ? str + mails.map do |mail|
          c = checked.nil? ? object.watched_by?(mail) : checked
          tag = check_box_tag 'issue[watcher_mails][]', mail, c, :id => nil
          content_tag 'label', "#{tag} #{h(mail)}".html_safe,
                      :id => "issue_watcher_mails_"+mail.gsub(/[^\w]+/, '_'),
                      :class => "floating"
        end.join.html_safe : str
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The syntax errors are in the last method (`watchers_checkboxes_with_anonymous`). The first error is:

```
 syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_cond, expecting ':'
        mails ? str + mails.map do |mail|
```

The second error is:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':'
        end.join.html_safe : str
```

And finally I get:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: if in doubt on operator precedence, just add parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Your ternary operator syntax at

```
mails ? str + mails.map do |mail|
```

is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This block:

```
mails ? str + mails.map do |mail|
      c = checked.nil? ? object.watched_by?(mail) : checked
      tag = check_box_tag 'issue[watcher_mails][]', mail, c, :id => nil
      content_tag 'label', "#{tag} #{h(mail)}".html_safe,
                  :id => "issue_watcher_mails_"+mail.gsub(/[^\w]+/, '_'),
                  :class => "floating"
    end.join.html_safe : str
```

should be rewritten as:

```
mails ? (str + mails.map do |mail|
      c = checked.nil? ? object.watched_by?(mail) : checked
      tag = check_box_tag 'issue[watcher_mails][]', mail, c, :id => nil
      content_tag 'label', "#{tag} #{h(mail)}".html_safe,
                  :id => "issue_watcher_mails_"+mail.gsub(/[^\w]+/, '_'),
                  :class => "floating"
    end.join.html_safe) : str
```

or, even better:

```
str.tap do |str|
  str << mails.map do |mail|
      c = checked.nil? ? object.watched_by?(mail) : checked
      tag = check_box_tag 'issue[watcher_mails][]', mail, c, :id => nil
      content_tag 'label', "#{tag} #{h(mail)}".html_safe,
                  :id => "issue_watcher_mails_"+mail.gsub(/[^\w]+/, '_'),
                  :class => "floating"
    end.join.html_safe if mails
end
```

The operator precedence matters.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That advanced me through this particular obstacle.

Regretfully, only to find out that this particular Redmine plugin does not work with the most recent version of Redmine (v3.2.0). 

Any chance any of you guys are using Redmine and have adapted the Anynymous Watchers plugin for Redmine 3.2.0 ?